# How to use Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using Zero/Shark on Ubuntu?

Tags: jdk, jvm

I have installed `openjdk-8-jre-zero_8u212-b03-0ubuntu1.16.04.1_amd64.deb` from http://debina.ktu.lt/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-8/

This suppose to be an Alternative JVM for OpenJDK, using Zero/Shark. When I type `java -zero -version` I get:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-8u212-b03-0ubuntu1.16.04.1-b03)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Zero VM (build 25.212-b03, interpreted mode)
```

The output is saying that JVM is in "interpreted mode", ie. without Shark JIT compiler (I guess it would be a "mixed mode" if Shark is used). Anyone know how to use this installation with Shark compiler?

Comment: I’m not sure, but there seems to be some issues with Shark itself due to the LLVM JIT changing between versions. As such, it is either due to be removed or has already been removed from OpenJDK sources, according to http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8189173

Comment: Thanks for the link! Information on Zero and Shark are very sparse, but this seems to indicate that it is dead. At least unless someone makes significant effort to bring it forward (for little gain over new native backends for the C2 compiler)